# Как разделить массив так, чтобы получился массив?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Данные генерируются: `test_arr = np.arange(55)`

Функция делит массив на вектора:

```py
def traincount(u, v): return [u[v:v+n] for v in range(0, len(u), n)]
```

Получилось: `[array([0,..9]), array([10,..19]),...]`

А нужен массив `[[0,..9], [10,..19],.. ]`.
Как получить желаемый результат?

Comment: `u[v:v+n].tolist()`

Comment: Либо наоборот сразу преобразовать `u` в обычный `list` и потом делать срезы.

Comment: test_arr.reshape(-1, 10)

Comment: Спасибо. Но через reshape не получается, потому что в последнем элементе не 10 значений будет. А смысл в том, чтобы преобразовать выборку не кратную 10ти.

Comment: u[v:v+n].tolist() Работает идеально))) Спасибо.